# How to convert a table with multiple y axes into a simple table?

Tags: excel, database-design, datatable, pivot

I have a table with 1 x-axis (Name) and 1 y-axes (Year, month, version). I want to convert this into a proper table which I can use in pivots - effectively, the table would have Name, Year, Month, Version and Value. Is there a way to do this

[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1M6v.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Sub SubRearrangeTable()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DblNameColumn As Double
    Dim DblYearRow As Double
    Dim DblMonthRow As Double
    Dim DblVersionRow As Double
    Dim DblValueRow As Double
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngDestination As Range
    Dim RngData As Range
    Dim WksData As Worksheet
    Dim WksNewTable As Worksheet
    
    'Setting RngData as the first top-left cell containint data.
    Set RngData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")
    
    'Setting variables to match the column and rows of each "non-Value" data.
    DblNameColumn = 1
    DblYearRow = 2
    DblMonthRow = 3
    DblVersionRow = 1
    
    'Resizing RngData to cover the entire list of data (the list is assumed to be a rectangle solidly filled in data).
    Set RngData = RngData.Parent.Range(RngData, RngData.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    
    'Setting WksData as the worksheet where the data list is located.
    Set WksData = RngData.Parent
    
    'Creating a new sheet where result will be posted.
    Set WksNewTable = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
    
    'Focusing WksNewTable.
    With WksNewTable
        
        'Filling the headers of the report.
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Year"
        .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Month"
        .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Verion"
        .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Value"
        
        'Setting RngDestination.
        Set RngDestination = .Cells(2, 1)
        
    End With
    
    'Covering all the cells in RngData.
    For Each RngTarget In RngData
        
        'Reporting the values accordingly.
        RngDestination.Offset(0, 0).Value = WksData.Cells(RngTarget.Row, DblNameColumn).Value
        RngDestination.Offset(0, 1).Value = WksData.Cells(DblYearRow, RngTarget.Column).Value
        RngDestination.Offset(0, 2).Value = WksData.Cells(DblMonthRow, RngTarget.Column).Value
        RngDestination.Offset(0, 3).Value = WksData.Cells(DblVersionRow, RngTarget.Column).Value
        RngDestination.Offset(0, 4).Value = RngTarget.Value
        Set RngDestination = RngDestination.Offset(1, 0)
    Next
        
End Sub
```

The code assumes that you list is located in range A1 of Sheet1 making the cell B4 the first cell with value. If that's not the case, just edit the line `Set RngData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")` accordingly. The code also assume that you table is solidly filled in data (no empty cells). If that's not the case, it might not cover the whole table. This can be solved, of course.

In case you are not familiar to VBA, to make the code work:

1. open your Excel file;
2. press Alt+F11;
3. in the new window that has appeared (Microsoft Visual Basic) from the sub-menu Insert select Module;
4. copy-paste the code in the blank module that has just appeared;
5. [optional] edit the code accordingly to your need as previously explained;
6. press F5; if another window named Macro pops-up, just make sure that SubRearrangeTable is selected and then click on Run.